# Issue of time wasting while downloading data from xml, what should I do?

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

In my blackberry application, I am taking data from xml and showing in labels,

but while fetching data from xml, it is taking time, what should I do and how ?
like to save in SDCard or in sqlite database, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi, Instead of XML use JSON format, i used this Json feed for my one J2ME application its not getting more time. [Check JSON web site](http://www.json.org/) Its very easy to write code for json.

Thanks

Comment: WHERE SHOULD I use it, on server where my xml is, or on my blackberry code?